# Chat message links from history pages take you to the current location of message, never original location

Tags: bug, chat

All of the links on the chat history page take you to the current location of the message, regardless of where it started out, despite there being link icons for each version.

As an example:

[image: Message History]

As you can see, this message was moved from Mos Eisley to the Trash.

Each of the three versions has a link icon when you hover. While you might expect this link (or the one below it) to take you to the spot in Mos Eisley this message was originally posted, it actually takes you to the Trash.

Unfortunately, the link to Mos Eisley also doesn't help as it takes you to the current state of the room, not the place the message came from.

I believe this is a bug and that the links for the older versions of the message should go to the original locations. This is important as it makes it possible to see the context of the message if necessary.

I know that the message doesn't exist in the original location any longer if moved but is there a way to still link to that prior location or is this [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design)?